# Highcharts Sankey colors not working for end column

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I'm having trouble setting the color of the end column of my highcharts sankey diagram. For customizing the colors I used the following option:

```js
      series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight', 'visible'],
        data: JSON.parse(this.data.get('flow-data')),
        nodes: JSON.parse(this.data.get('node-data')),
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'segments',
        linkOpacity: 0.0
      }]
```

I'm setting the colors for each node as followed:

```js
[{"id":"1?0","column":1,"color":"rgba(222, 27, 0, 1.0)"},
{"id":"2?0","column":1,"color":"rgba(194, 31, 9, 0.917)"},
{"id":"3?0","column":1,"color":"rgba(166, 35, 18, 0.833)"},
{"id":"4?0","column":1,"color":"rgba(138, 39, 27, 0.75)"},
{"id":"5?0","column":1,"color":"rgba(110, 43, 36, 0.667)"},
{"id":"1?1","column":2,"color":"rgba(222, 27, 0, 1.0)"},
{"id":"2?1","column":2,"color":"rgba(194, 31, 9, 0.917)"},
{"id":"3?1","column":2,"color":"rgba(166, 35, 18, 0.833)"},
{"id":"4?1","column":2,"color":"rgba(138, 39, 27, 0.75)"},
{"id":"5?1","column":2,"color":"rgba(110, 43, 36, 0.667)"},
{"id":"5?2","column":3,"color":"rgba(110, 43, 36, 0.667)"},
{"id":"1?2","column":3,"color":"rgba(222, 27, 0, 1.0)"},
{"id":"2?2","column":3,"color":"rgba(194, 31, 9, 0.917)"},
{"id":"3?2","column":3,"color":"rgba(166, 35, 18, 0.833)"},
{"id":"4?2","column":3,"color":"rgba(138, 39, 27, 0.75)"},
{"id":"1?3","column":4,"color":"rgba(222, 27, 0, 1.0)"},
{"id":"2?3","column":4,"color":"rgba(194, 31, 9, 0.917)"},
{"id":"3?3","column":4,"color":"rgba(166, 35, 18, 0.833)"},
{"id":"4?3","column":4,"color":"rgba(138, 39, 27, 0.75)"},
{"id":"5?3","column":4,"color":"rgba(110, 43, 36, 0.667)"},
{"id":"1?4","column":5,"color":"rgba(222, 27, 0, 1.0)"},
{"id":"2?4","column":5,"color":"rgba(194, 31, 9, 0.917)"},
{"id":"3?4","column":5,"color":"rgba(166, 35, 18, 0.833)"},
{"id":"4?4","column":5,"color":"rgba(138, 39, 27, 0.75)"},
{"id":"5?4","column":5,"color":"rgba(110, 43, 36, 0.667)"},
{"id":"1?6","column":6,"color":"rgba(222, 27, 0, 1.0)"},
{"id":"2?6","column":6,"color":"rgba(194, 31, 9, 0.917)"},
{"id":"3?6","column":6,"color":"rgba(166, 35, 18, 0.833)"},
{"id":"4?6","column":6,"color":"rgba(138, 39, 27, 0.75)"},
{"id":"5?6","column":6,"color":"rgba(110, 43, 36, 0.667)"}]
```

Everything works fine, except the last column (6), which is generated somehow by highcharts doesn't apply to the specified color.

This is the result:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deXK8.png)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4o49ydt/1/)

Comment: Can you make a live example, .e.g on jsfiddle?

Comment: @morganfree Here you go ;) https://jsfiddle.net/p4o49ydt/1/

Comment: It looks like your ids in the data are not correct. You set 5?6 in nodes but  it is not present in the data, you set 1?6 in the data but it is not defined in nodes - I swapped the ids and the color (blue) is set https://jsfiddle.net/7g70teax/

Comment: Thanks a lot @morganfree! It works now.